# How to determine time at which PC was woken

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a function in Excel VBA that returns the time elapsed since the PC was last woken up from sleep or hibernate? Or when it was booted? Whichever was most recent?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to figure out last time PC was booted up.  It's in Visual Basic:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/determine-the-time-since-the-last-boot-up-in-visual-basic3/

I haven't seen anything that may return the time of when it was woken up, though.

Comment: Really need it to work after it has been woken unfort. Have gone through endless contortion by writing a VBA routine based on Application.OnTime() and this nearly works, but not quite due to various very frustrating querks! A simple operating system call would be much better if one exists - can't help but think there must be one somewhere...